# Opening an existing Tower git repo from the command line

Tags: macos, git

I'm running the [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) git client on OS X and want to be able to open it to a repo already on disk and added to its list. Looking at their [custom URL scheme documentation](http://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/integration/url-scheme), it seems like it might be possible:

> `gittower://openRepo/git@example.beanstalkapp.com:/project.git`
>
> Called like this, the Tower app will open and offer to either clone or open the given repository.

When I do this, though, I'm always prompted with the clone dialog, regardless if Tower knows about the repo in question. A command like the following seems like it should open the existing repo, but it too shows the clone dialog:

```
cd reponame
open gittower://openRepo/`git remote -v | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

I've also tried the `file:///`-based path to the on-disk repo as well, which results in *no* dialog at all.

Has anyone had success opening Tower to an existing repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way!

Under Preferences → Integration, you can install a command line tool, `gittower`, which can open a local repo. You use it by calling `gittower /path/to/repo`. `gittower .` works nicely if your current directory is a clone of the repo in question.